# Swift - associated types in protocol with where clause?

Tags: swift, swift2, associated-types

Consider the following:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
  typealias F: Foo
  typealias FB: FooBar where FB.Foo == F
}
```

But this doesn't compile since we cannot put `where` clause in `typealias` like that.

I must be missing something here since this can be easily done with `type parameterization` like this:

```
struct SomeStruct<F: Foo, FB: FooBar where FB.Foo == F> {}
```

**What's the `where` clause equivalent for `associated type`**?

Comment: A similar problem is part of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843038/define-a-swift-protocol-which-requires-a-specific-type-of-sequence.

Comment: You're not missing anything. This isn't currently possible in Swift.

Comment: This has been requested via Radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/17203060, http://www.openradar.me/21441502, and mentioned on swift-evolution: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160229/011666.html (see heading "*Arbitrary requirements in protocols"), but I don't think anyone's created an evolution proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Type parameterization of associated types in protocols is currently not supported in Swift (2.1).

Although in this case you don't even need the where clause for functionality. It's more the convenience you get where you can do this:

```
func someFunc<T: SomeProtocol>(someProt: T, foo: T.F) {
    ...
}

// Instead of this:

func someFunc<T: SomeProtocol>(someProt: T, foo: T.FB.Foo) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well, yes you are right. But this was a contrived example for simplicity. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @DanielShin While where clauses in protocols would be nice, in almost every case a generic protocol like `SequenceType<T>` would be the solution.... Hoping for Swift 3

Comment: @Qbyte yes. a generic protocol, if available, means exactly the same as 'generic' typealias from the question. it is just different syntax for the same behavior. there is lot of arguments for generic protocols and a lot of them against. in real world we can very easy to survive without generic protocols. translating our sw from other languages is the worst, we can do. i prefer that swift will stabilize for a while, i am looking for better xcode support, refactoring, open source version of standard library, first. and next, generic protocols would be available as an 'extra bonus'