# Swift: 'Abort trap: 6 - pointer being freed was not allocated' with class where clause

Tags: swift, swift2

Consider the following:

```
protocol DataContainer {
  typealias Data
}

protocol Foo {
  typealias FooBar: DataContainer
  typealias FooBaz: DataContainer
  typealias Schema
}

final class FooClass<F: Foo where F.Schema == F.FooBar.Data, F.Schema == F.FooBaz.Data> {}
```

This fairly *expressive* `where` clause doesn't compile with cryptic error message:

> Command failed due to signal: Abort trap 6
>     ...
>     swift(4946,0x7fff777c9300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5a5fbfe0: pointer being freed was not allocated

which, to me, makes absolutely no sense. I've confirmed that the error goes away when I remove the `where` clause constraint like this:

```
final class FooClass<F: Foo> {}
```

I know this is a long shot in the dark, but has anyone experienced this?

And if so, any workaround that you've found?

---

Addendum: This could have been completely avoided **if** swift allowed expressing equality constraint **inside** the `protocol` itself instead of leaking constraints into its implementer. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871490/swift-associated-types-in-protocol-with-where-clause).

Comment: That "cryptic error message" looks more like a Swift compiler crash to me. If so, you should create a minimal example and report it to Apple at bugreport.apple.com. For what it's worth, I get a different error `'Data' is not a member type of 'F.FooBar'` which makes much more sense. (Xcode 7.1.1)

Comment: @JeremyP I'm aware that it is compiler crash. It is pretty obvious by its message alone without pointing out. What I meant by **cryptic** was its irrelevancy to the code at hand. And I've already reported. Thanks.

Comment: From the text of your question, it was not obvious that you realised that you had a compiler crash on your hands. I was not, btw, criticising your question or suggesting you shouldn't ask it because of that, I was merely trying to make sure that Apple are made aware of the issue so it can be fixed. Whether your code is wrong or not, if it crashes the compiler, it's a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @JeremyP I apologize for overreacting. I was rather frustrated with swift with few compiler issues lately. Hope you have a great day!

Comment: I've been using Swift since the first beta was announced so I completely understand your frustration. There are still far too many compiler crashes and it can often take a while to locate the line that causes them.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So after a few more brute-force debugging, I've found out that if I use the same `type` names for the constrained parameters, it does compile.

So for example,

```
protocol Foo {
  typealias FooBar
  typealias FooBaz
  typealias Data
}
final class FooClass<F: Foo where F.Data == F.FooBar.Data, F.Data == F.FooBaz.Data> {}
```

This **will** compile. Note that all I did was to change `Schema` to `Data`. This is definitely a bug.

-EDIT: And is reported accordingly.