# Returning a Sequence in Swift 3

Tags: swift, sequence

I have a protocol `Points` with a method that should return an ordered sequence of `Point` instances.

I could return an array, but can I return something more generic so that implementations of `Points` needn't copy data in to an array?

I tried to do this:

```
protocol Points {
  var points: Sequence {get}
}
```

But get the error:

> Protocol 'Sequence' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

In older questions I read about `SequenceOf`, but this doesn't seem to exist in Swift 3.

Here's an example implementation of the `Points` protocol:

```
extension PointSetNode: Points {
  var points: ?????? {
    return children.map{$0.points}.joined()
  }
}
```

… here, `children` is an array.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/33843038/2976878 – you want `AnySequence`, which is the equivalent of Swift 1's `SequenceOf`.

Comment: Lovely, yes, that does it. Would you like to make that an answer? Otherwise I'm happy to self answer.

Comment: Hmmm, I'd say might as well just close as dupe – but if you feel adding a self-answer would be beneficial, go for it :)

Comment: Well, I didn't hit an answer googling and searching for "return a sequence with swift", which is why I asked. So it might be useful :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Hamish mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619438/returning-a-sequence-in-swift-3?noredirect=1#comment76224863_44619438) you should use `AnySequence` for this. The protocol definition will be:

```
protocol Points {
  var points: AnySequence<Point> {get}
}
```

An implementation of this might be:

```
var points: AnySequence<Point> {
  return AnySequence(children.map{$0.points}.joined())
}
```