# Pass Array or FetchedResults as an argument to method

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I have two identical methods that differ in the argument they receive. One receives an `Array<Entity>` and the other one a `FetchedResults<Entity>` object, where `Entity` is a CoreData Entity. It would be nice to simplify code by removing the duplication and only having one method.

```swift
    static func groupByDate(_ result : FetchedResults<Entity>)-> [[Entity]]{
        return  Dictionary(grouping: result){ $0.dateDescription }
            .values
            .map{$0}
            .sorted(by: { $0.first!.timestamp! > $1.first!.timestamp! })
    }
    
    static func groupByDate(_ result : [Entity])-> [[Entity]]{
        return  Dictionary(grouping: result){ $0.dateDescription }
            .values
            .map{$0}
            .sorted(by: { $0.first!.timestamp! > $1.first!.timestamp! })
    }
```

I tried to [use a sequence of the Entity type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843038/define-a-swift-protocol-which-requires-a-specific-type-of-sequence) to abstract the method because both `Array<Entity>` and `FetchedRusults<Entity>` adhere to the protocol. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get it to work.

I'm curious how you would solve it.

Comment: you could use just `groupByDate(_ result: [Entity])...` and when you have 
`FetchedResults<Entity>` to pass to it, use `groupByDate(entities.map{$0})`.

Comment: That would be possible, but it would iterate unnecessarily over the sequence. I was curious about how to solve the problem with generics to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `FetchedResults` and `Array` conform to the `Sequence` protocol so you can use that as a generic type and have a `where` condition to only allow `Sequence` types that has `Entity` as it content

```
static func groupByDate<Values: Sequence>(_ result: Values) -> [[Entity]] where Values.Element == Entity {
    return Dictionary(grouping: result, by: { $0.dateDescription })
        .values
        .sorted(by: { $0.first!.timestamp! > $1.first!.timestamp! })
}
```

Comment: This worked out. Thanks! :)